# Set of icons available to download freely

Tags: free, download, icon

I need to use icons in my website.

It has facility to add, edit, search, review etc. So I need to use Icons for the same.

I tried googling but not getting it as expected.

Can someone help me to get a set of Icon (free, not paid) for all basic functionality for dynamic website.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at these:

- Font Awesome - http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/
- Foundation Icon Fonts - http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icons
- Bootstrap Icons (Glyphs) - http://getbootstrap.com/components/
- TypIcons - http://typicons.com/
- Modern Pictograms - http://thedesignoffice.org/project/modern-pictograms
- Fontello - http://fontello.com/

All are free to use and should cover more than the basic needs.

Comment: Thanks, This is really helpful. I've come acorss some of this links while googling. This all are either single color or wrapped around fonts. My requirement is to have colorful icons which includes add,edit,delete,review,update etc. basic operation.

Comment: something like this one http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

Comment: these are not "icons", but glyphs or icon fonts even, which allow you to set color, size etc. Please take some time and read more information on how to use them in their documentation.

Comment: Yes, I've gone through the instructions. But as of my requirement I need ICON files in .pnf or .gif format. Hope it clears the question.